# hadoop fs -rm -skipTrash doesn't work

Tags: hadoop, rm, distcp

I copied some files from a directory to directory using

```
hadoop distcp -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=adhoc /user/comverse/data/$CURRENT_DATE_NO_DASH_*/*rcr.gz /apps/hive/warehouse/arstel.db/fair_usage/fct_evkuzmin04/file_rcr/
```

I stopped the scipt before it finished and the remained a lot of `.distcp.tmp.attempt` and files that fnished moving in the dst directory

Now I want to clean the dst directory. After running

```
hadoop fs -rm -skipTrash /apps/hive/warehouse/arstel.db/fair_usage/fct_evkuzmin04/file_mta/*
```

most of the files were deleted, but some remained(at least that's what HUE shows). The strange thing is, every time I run `hadoop fs -rm -skipTrash`, according to HUE, the number of remaining files changes to more or less.

I tried

```
hadoop fs -ls /apps/hive/warehouse/arstel.db/fair_usage/fct_evkuzmin04/file_mta/
```

and saw that some of the files that should be deleted were still there. Then I run

```
hadoop fs -rm -skipTrash /apps/hive/warehouse/arstel.db/fair_usage/fct_evkuzmin04/file_mta/*
```

a dozen more times and there were always more files to delete(There still are). What is happening?

ALSO

Each time I refresh the page in hue, the number of files grows. HALP.

EDIT

It seems that stopping distcp in the command line doesn't actually kill the job. That was the reason.

Comment: How are you stopping from command line ?

Comment: Can you share `distcp` submit log ?

Comment: @San Ctrl + c for stopping. I can't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Ctrl + C` doesn't kill the yarn application. `distcp` uses `MapReduce` model to copy data. When you run `distcp` command it submit yarn application to run on hadoop to copy data. You need to kill the yarn application to stop `distcp` copy process.

Command to kill yarn application:

`yarn application -kill <application_id>`

Answer (score 11):

**You could use this** **"-R":**

This remove all the file from your hdfs location.

```
hadoop fs -rm -R -skipTrash /apps/hive/warehouse/arstel.db/fair_usage/fct_evkuzmin04/file_mta/*
```